# Propagating API JSON results as option list

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I'm building a simple news app in react.
I'm fetching my API from newsapi.org and am trying to show the news sources options in a list in my select component.

However, it's currently showing each news source as a new separate option instead of listing it all in one option component. 
(Sorry if this is hard to understand, English is not my first language. As such, I have included screenshots along with my code).

Thanks all in advance.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://beta.newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=XXX')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
        let sources = data.sources.map((src) => {
            return(
                <div key={src.sources}>
                   <select className="form-control form-inline">
                       <option value={src.id}>{src.name}</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
            )
        })
        this.setState({sources: sources});
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h2>Select a news source:</h2>
            {this.state.sources}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your mapping should be returning individual `option`s, nested under a parent `select`. The way you are currently mapping it returns individual `option` elements with its own `select` element.

Comment: @char sorry, i don't exactly understand. pretty new to javascript. could you expand on that a little please, if you don't mind?

Comment: For every element in `data.sources`, you are returning 
    <select><option></option></select>. The end result is multiple select/option elements. What you want is <select> <option></option><option></option><option></option><option></option><option></option>.....</select>.

Comment: @char perfect explanation! I fixed it by fixing it in my render method. thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

I see that @char has solved the problem for you. Still, here is the code.
Also, it is better practice to store only the "data" in state and then render your view inside "render" function, using the state.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  //other code

  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://beta.newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=XXX')
      .then(results => {
          return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
          this.setState({sources: data.sources});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <h2>Select a news source:</h2>
        <SelectComponent sources={this.state.sources} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const SelectComponent = ({sources})=>(
  <select className="form-control form-inline">
    {sources.map((source)=>
      <option value={source.id} key={source.id} > {source.name} </option>
    )}
  </select>
);
```